# How can I load an image by an uri in drupal 8?

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-8

I wrote a custom template with a customtemplate_preprocess_image function.

In this function I have only $variables['uri'] at my disposal to load the same image but with a different image style. The uri is of this format:
'/sites/default/files/styles/image_xs/public/2019-02/IMG_20181219_135712499_0.jpg?itok=1faUCioy'

If I now do this

```
$style = ImageStyle::load('image_lightbox');
$image = \Drupal::service('image.factory')->get($variables['uri']);
if ($image->isValid()) {
    print("Image url: ".$variables['uri'].'<br>');
}
else {
    print("Image invalid: ".$variables['uri'].'<br>');
}
```

It renders "Image invalid: /sites/default/files/styles/image_xs/public/2019-02/IMG_20181219_135712499_0.jpg?itok=1faUCioy

Why? And how can I solve this having only this uri?

Comment: Can you get the image target_id instead?  And then with that, use the getSource so that you're starting with the base image and not a derived image.  See https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Image%21Image.php/class/Image/8.2.x

Answer (score 1):

You can use file uri in twig file on drupal 8.

```
{{ file_url(node.field_image.entity.fileuri) }}
```

Comment: How can I access the $entity variable inside the image_preprocess function? $variables['entity'] does not exist.

Comment: Try from this way to get image in _preprocess_image
`$styled_image_url = ImageStyle::load('image_lightbox')->buildUrl($node->field_image->entity->getFileUri());`

Comment: Thanks but the $node variable is not accessible in preprocess image